# WSO2 Not a valid protocol version: <head> For

Tags: json, http, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm trying to call a *http-EndPoint* with *POST* method in WSO2 Enterprise Integrator. This EndPoint gets a *JSON* object as input and return a JSON object as response.

Until now I've used various types of http-EndPoints in Enterprise Integrator without any problem but this particular EndPoint returns an error message which I'm not able to find any clue about it in google.

This is my api:

```
<resource methods="POST" uri-template="/userInfo">
    <inSequence>
        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "params": {"auth_type": "ADMIN", "auth_name": "someName", "normal_username": "$1", "auth_pass": "myPassword"},"method": "user.MethodName", "id": 0}
            </format>
            <args>
                <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.user"/>
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
        <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
        <property name="FORCE_HTTP_1.0" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
        <send description="">
            <endpoint>
                <http method="post" uri-template="http://192.168.1.50:1237"/>
            </endpoint>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
</resource>
```

This is my error message in console:

> [EI-Core] ERROR - TargetHandler HTTP protocol violation : Not a valid protocol version: `<head>` For : 192.168.1.50:1237

**UPDATE**

I [enabled Wire Logs in WSO2](http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/how-to-enable-wire-logs-in-wso2-esbapim.html) to investigate in depth about this issue. Here is log output:

```
[2018-01-15 09:30:46,621] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "POST  HTTP/1.0[\r][\n]"
[2018-01-15 09:30:46,622] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Expect: 100-continue[\r][\n]"
[2018-01-15 09:30:46,622] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2018-01-15 09:30:46,622] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Content-Length: 196[\r][\n]"
[2018-01-15 09:30:46,622] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Host: 192.168.1.50:1237[\r][\n]"
[2018-01-15 09:30:46,622] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2018-01-15 09:30:46,622] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"
[2018-01-15 09:30:46,622] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "[\r][\n]"
[2018-01-15 09:30:46,622] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 << "{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "params": {"auth_type": "ADMIN", "auth_name": "someName", "normal_username": "myUserName", "auth_pass": "myPassword", "remote_addr": "127.0.0.1"},"method": "user.MethodName", "id": 0}"
[2018-01-15 09:30:46,623] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "<head>[\n]"
[2018-01-15 09:30:46,623] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "<title>Error response</title>[\n]"
[2018-01-15 09:30:46,624] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "</head>[\n]"
[2018-01-15 09:30:46,624] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "<body>[\n]"
[2018-01-15 09:30:46,624] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "<h1>Error response</h1>[\n]"
[2018-01-15 09:30:46,624] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "<p>Error code 400.[\n]"
[2018-01-15 09:30:46,624] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "<p>Message: Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('POST').[\n]"
[2018-01-15 09:30:46,624] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "<p>Error code explanation: 400 = Bad request syntax or unsupported method.[\n]"
[2018-01-15 09:30:46,624] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "</body>[\n]"
```

Although wire log returned this response: `Message: Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('POST')`, but I can send post requests to Endpoint directly without any problem.

Here is direct post request to endpoint:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "params": {"auth_type": "ADMIN", "auth_name": "someName", "normal_username": "myUserName", "auth_pass": "myPassword", "remote_addr": "127.0.0.1"}, "method": "user.MethodName", "id": 0}' 192.168.1.50:1237
```

And here is output result:

> - STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x600057950; line 1423 (connection #-5000)
> - Rebuilt URL to: http://192.168.1.50:1237/
> - Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
> - Trying 5.202.129.107...
> - TCP_NODELAY set
> - STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x600057950; line 1475 (connection #0)
> - Connected to 192.168.1.50 (192.168.1.50) port 1237 (#0)
> - STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x600057950; line 1592 (connection #0)
> - Marked for [keep alive]: HTTP default
> - STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x600057950; line 1610 (connection #0)
>
>   > POST / HTTP/1.1
>   >     Host: http://192.168.1.50:1237
>   >     User-Agent: curl/7.56.1
>   >     Accept: */*
>   >     Content-Type: application/json
>   >     Content-Length: 197
> - upload completely sent off: 197 out of 197 bytes
> - STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x600057950; line 1689 (connection #0)
> - STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x600057950; line 1814 (connection #0)
> - STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x600057950; line 1824 (connection #0)
> - HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
> - Marked for [closure]: HTTP/1.0 close after body < HTTP/1.0 200 OK < Server: BaseHTTP/0.3 Python/2.7.9 < Date: Sun, 14 Jan 2018 07:53:37
>     GMT < Content-type: application/json < Content-length: 2105 <
> - STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x600057950; line 1993 (connection #0)
> - multi_done
> - Closing connection 0
> - The cache now contains 0 members
> - Expire cleared

When I compare headers from WSO2 to headers from curl I cant figure out what are differences. Why WSO2 request failed while curl request succeed?

Comment: Can you hit the backend directly with `curl -IL` and post the response?

Comment: @Bee Thank you for reply. I updated my question.

Comment: Well, what I wanted you to do is to run that command with a real request (i.e. working url and valid payload)

Comment: @Bee Can you help me to do this Please? I've tried this: `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "params": {"auth_type": "ADMIN", "auth_name": "someName", "normal_username": "myUserName", "auth_pass": "myPassword", "remote_addr": "127.0.0.1"}, "method": "user.MethodName", "id": 0}' 192.168.1.50:1237 -IL` But it respond: `Warning: You can only select one HTTP request method! You asked for both POST
Warning: (-d, --data) and HEAD (-I, --head).`

Comment: Can you run this and post the response headers you get?
`curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "params": {"auth_type": "ADMIN", "auth_name": "someName", "normal_username": "myUserName", "auth_pass": "myPassword", "remote_addr": "127.0.0.1"}, "method": "user.MethodName", "id": 0}' 192.168.1.50:1237`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By comparing headers from WSO2 and curl I noticed this line in curl header `Rebuilt URL to: http://192.168.1.50:1237/`. Hence I changed this:

```
<endpoint>
     <http method="post" uri-template="http://192.168.1.50:1237"/>
</endpoint>
```

To this:

```
<endpoint>
     <http method="post" uri-template="http://192.168.1.50:1237/"/>
</endpoint>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this before the `<send>` mediator.

```
<property name="FORCE_HTTP_1.0" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
```

Comment: I thought it solved the problem. But unfortunately I still get this error message: 'Not a valid protocol version: <head> For : 192.168.1.50:1237'

Comment: Enabled wire logs and invoke the API. then post your logs. http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-enable-wire-logs-in-wso2-esbapim.html

Comment: Thanks. Enabling wire log was a huge help. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following properties to the sequence:

- `FORCE_HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH`
- `COPY_CONTENT_LENGTH_FROM_INCOMING`

This solves the problem, but the reason still unknown.

Answer (score 0):

from your wire log:

> [2018-01-15 09:30:46,624] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O
>   dispatcher-1 >> "
>
> Message: Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('POST').[\n]"
>   [2018-01-15 09:30:46,624] [EI-Core] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Sender I/O
>   dispatcher-1 >> "
>
> Error code explanation: 400 = Bad request syntax
>   or unsupported method.[\n]" [2018-01-15 09:30:46,624] [EI-Core] DEBUG
>   - wire HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1 >> "[\n]"

Note: The official HTTP 0.9 specification included only one request method: GET.
you are using post which is not supported in HTTP 0.9

[For more information about HTTP 0.9, refer to the original W3C HTTP specification.](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html)